# AWS Lex latency

Tags: amazon-web-services, performance, latency, amazon-lex

I'm currently seeing Lex sometimes take 0.9 seconds to 1.3 seconds to respond. These numbers are based on the Cloudwatch RuntimeSuccessfulRequestLatency metric. These times are for simple audio inputs such as "I would like to eat."

At other times, Lex responds within 400 ms. to 600 ms. to the same input. This latency is barely acceptable to our users but anything over 600 ms. does not make for a good user experience.

How can Lex latency be reduced and made consistent?

Thanks!
John